# Can't acccess web api (Azure Container instances)

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I have pushed the following image to the registry in Azure:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WEBAPI.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./WEBAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WEBAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WEBAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WEBAPI.dll"]
```

This is a simple web api.

I have then started a Aazure Container Instance of this, and it starts without problem.
However, when I try to navigate to my api using the generated IP adress, 20.67.203.151 and also the FQDN, dockerapi.northeurope.azurecontainer.io, i can't access it, and I really don't know why.

I have followed this guide: https://medium.com/@krishjan05/deploy-a-net-core-web-application-to-azure-container-instance-b016c321b1de

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here are some information
[image]

Comment: please show the command which you used to create the ACI like this `az container create `

Comment: @silent: az container create -g Test --name dockerapi --image bryantestregistry.azurecr.io/docker-api-image:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1 --dns-name-label dockerapi --port 80

Comment: should be `--ports` (with the s) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: @silent it stil don't work. I can't access my api.

Comment: @silent: The container has the status "Running".

Comment: @silent: I can see that the container has the State "Waiting" when you go to Containers in the Azure portal. What does that mean?

Comment: can you paste what do you see in logs

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I don't have any logs. Check my updated question. It seems that it get stuck when it tries to pull the image from the registry?

Comment: you can check the logs from the portal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal

Comment: @Sajeetharan: yes, and it says "No logs available
"

Comment: @Sajeetharan why does my container have the state "Waiting" and not "Running"?

Comment: did you try to run it locally from the ACR?

Comment: @Sajeetharan what do u mean? I have tried to run the application locally using docker. And it works. I tested to create a container instance based of the mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld-latest, and that works perfectly. But when i choose the image located in the registry, it don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see, the issue could be that your ACI is not able to pull the image from the ACR, you could validate that with DockerHub registry and try to reset the credentials

Comment: I managed to get it to work by following this guide exactly the way he does it: https://medium.com/@krishjan05/deploy-a-net-core-web-application-to-azure-container-instance-b016c321b1de